# Mapbox points show on the map when they are a circle, and not when they are a symbol

Tags: maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I have a map layer and when it's styled as a symbol not all points are shown. But when it's styled as a circle, all points show.

Some points show, just not all of them.

When I hide all other map layers on the map the symbols seems to work better.

All points show:

```
map.addLayer({
    id: 'layer-1',
    type: 'circle',
    source: 'source',
    'source-layer': 'source-layer1',
    paint: {
      'circle-color': '#FF0000',
      'circle-radius': 8,
    },
  });
```

Only some points show:

```
map.addLayer({
  id: 'layer-1',
  type: 'symbol',
  source: 'source',
  'source-layer': 'source-layer1',
  layout: {
    'icon-image': 'pointImage', // reference the image
    'icon-allow-overlap': true,
    'text-allow-overlap': true,
    'icon-ignore-placement': true,
    'text-ignore-placement': true,
    'icon-size': 1,
    'text-optional': true,
  },
});
```

I have tried various configuration options on the symbol to allow all of the points to show but with no success.

When I remove all other layers from the map, the symbols seem to work better.

Comment: [@Jason Kinnear](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22974314/jason-kinnear) are you using an image sprite or an `addImage` call to declare your `pointImage`?  It seems like your config on your `icon-image` is likely the problem.